# Get post data from a website using firefox addon or any other tool

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, http-post

I want to get the post request data of a website. Is there any tool  or addon for this? I can't see in the browser firebug as the page refreshes when the browser sends a request.

Comment: I like [LiveHTTPHeaders addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)

Comment: Also [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/?src=ss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Httpfox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/).

You can see all the incoming and outgoing http traffic with it